# Angular - inject directive into other directive for the same element

Tags: angular

Let's say I have this piece of code

```
<div *appTab routerLink="..." routerLinkActive="..."></div>
```

Is it possible to inject the `RouterLinkActive` Directive instance into my `appTab` Directive?

Comment: Yes, I think you can just add it to the constructor.

Comment: @Reactgular tried, unfortunately it doesn't work. `nullInjectorError: No provider for RouterLinkActive`

Comment: @Reactgular routerLinkActive is inside of appTab structural directive.

Comment: @LiamFleming Then he will get completely different instance of RouterLinkActive directive

Comment: I'm not sure what the class name is for the router link. I don't have my IDE open right now, but I thought it was named something like RouterLinkActiveDirective

Comment: @Reactgular `RouterLinkActive` is the correct name

Comment: Why are you prefixing the directive with `*`? Is this directive a structural template?

Comment: @Reactgular yep! The `div` will be picked up with `@ContentChildren`

Comment: I'm wondering if this is why you can't inject it. The `<div>` will be relocated to an inner template by the compiler. Try removing the `*` just to see if the injection works.

Comment: @Reactgular tried, doesn't work. What a pity.

Comment: Not sure if that has a chance to work: `<div #rla="routerLinkActive" [appTabRouterLinkActive]="rla" ...>`, where `appTabRouterLinkActive` would be an `@Input` property in `appTab`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan unfortunately structural directives doesn't seem to accept Inputs this way

Comment: You can try to implement the `@Input` property with the technique suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41791130/1009922). You may also have to make the correction suggested in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50036831/1009922).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier if ViewContainerRefs.createEmbeddedView [used correct injector](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14935) but for now we can only workaround it.

**router-link-active-tab-connector.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TabDirective } from './tab.directive';
import { RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLinkActive][routerLinkActiveTabConnector]'
})
export class RouterLinkActiveLinkerDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('routerLinkActiveTabConnector') tab: TabDirective;

  constructor(private routerLinkActive: RouterLinkActive) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tab.setRouterLinkActive(this.routerLinkActive);
  }
}
```

**tab.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTab]'
})
export class TabDirective {

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) { }

  setRouterLinkActive(routerLinkActive: RouterLinkActive) {
    console.log(routerLinkActive);
    // do something with RouterLinkActive directive
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef, { $implicit: this});
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<div *appTab="let tabRef" 
  routerLink="..." 
  routerLinkActive="" 
  [routerLinkActiveTabConnector]="tabRef">
   Some content
</div>
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/0P95XFRlgm34aO1yUtSl?open=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: A bit contorted but it works! Maybe with Ivy things will get even better. Thank you!