# Not able to pass Input value in my custom Directive - Angular

Tags: angular, directive

I am trying to pass some value in my custom Directive but when trying to do so, I am getting error

**home.component.ts**

```
<div *myNgIf myNgIfSomething="true" class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lname">LastName</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
 @Directive({
    selector: '[myNgIf]'
})
export class myNgIfDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() myNgIfSomething: boolean = false;

    constructor(private container: ViewContainerRef, private template: TemplateRef<any>) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if(this.myNgIfSomething){
            this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template)
        }else{
            this.container.clear()
        }
    }

}
```

**error**

[image]

Comment: I tried, but it is still giving me error, I am able to run the code successfully with this code,<ng-template myNgIf [myNgIfSomething]="true">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lname">LastName</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname">
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
but i want to implement the directive syntetic sugar

Comment: @mbojko, it says, it should be prefixed with the directive name followed by the input name captilized, which is exactly i am using but i am getting error

Comment: it's not how you consume a custom structural directive in a template. Just like that's not the syntax for the standard structural directives you get OOTB. You write `*ngIf="someCondition; else refToAnotherTemplate"`.

Comment: @mbojko, could you guide me on what is the proper way to get an input from the directive, I couldnt find that in any blog

Comment: The first answer in the thread I linked above provides all parts: the logic of the directive, and how do you actually use it in a template.

Comment: as suggested by @mbojko, this post answers the question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789702/how-to-use-angular-structural-directive-with-multiple-inputs

Answer (score -2):

You forgot the brackets while setting your input in the template. It should be:

```
<div *myNgIf [myNgIfSomething]="true" class="col-sm-6">
```

When setting an HTML node property inside the template, you use the brackets, then you have a javascript expression between the quotes. In your case, you want the JS value "true" for this "property", so use the brackets. Otherwise, Angular will interpret this property as a string, just like a normal property of an HTML node.

Comment: That's for attribute directives (used without asterisk). For structural directives, you use inputs differently: `*myNgIf="someValue; something anotherValue`.

Comment: Well, this is definitely what his error is saying. He sets the selector has an attribute directive, has an myNgIfSomething Input and calls it without brackets. So using brackets and removing the asterisk would work.